# Get all included Active Record objects of collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

Is there any way of getting all objects, included in Active Relation query?
Something like this:

```
def index
  @items = Item.all.includes(:comments)
  @comments = @items.comments // No such method for AR Collection :(
end
```

The obvious way to get all the items in this case is:

```
@comments = @items.map(&:comments).flatten.uniq
```

Thanks to using `.includes(:comments)` there should be no N+1 queries, but I worry about the performance of this code. Are there any built-in or more effective ways of getting all included records of collection?

Comment: Why do you want all comments in a separate object `@comments`? How are you going to use it exactly?

Comment: It really depends on what you intend to do with `@comments` - do you need them in any specific order?

Answer (score 0):

You can request comments like this:

```
@comments = Comment.where(item_id: Item.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: You can do the same thing in one query with `@comments = Comment.where.not(item_id: nil)` if only care that it is attached to a Item.

Comment: I would not recommend this. You perform two queries where you could easily do with one

Comment: But you will get ActiveRecord collection instead of pure array, like in question's example